# Java MultiMap Not Recognizing Key

Tags: java, hashmap, multimap

I'm trying to store multiple values for a key in a data structure so I'm using Guava (Google Collection)'s MultiMap.

```
Multimap<double[], double[]> destinations = HashMultimap.create();
destinations = ArrayListMultimap.create();

double[] startingPoint = new double[] {1.0, 2.0};
double[] end = new double[] {3.0, 4.0};
destinations.put(startingPoint, end);

System.out.println(destinations.containsKey(startingPoint));
```

and it returns false.

Note: Key-values are being stored in the multimap as the `destinations.size()` increases when I put something there.It also does not happen when keys are `String` instead of `double[]`.

Any idea what the problem is?

Edit: Many thanks to Jon Skeet I now implemented the class:

```
class Point {

    double lat;
    double lng;

    public boolean equals(Point p) {

        if (lat == p.lat && lng == p.lng)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        int hash = 29;
        hash = hash*41 + (int)(lat * 100000);
        hash = hash*41 + (int)(lng * 100000);

        return hash;
    }

    public Point(double newlat, double newlng) {
        lat = newlat;
        lng = newlng;
    }
}
```

And now I have a new problem. This is how I'm using it:

```
Multimap<Point, Point> destinations = HashMultimap.create();
destinations = ArrayListMultimap.create();

Point startingPoint = new Point(1.0, 2.0);
Point end = new Point(3.0, 4.0);
destinations.put(startingPoint, end);

System.out.println( destinations.containsKey(startingPoint) );
System.out.println( destinations.containsKey(new Point(1.0, 2.0)) );
```

The first one returns true, the second one returns false. It gives me an error if I put `@Override` before the `equals` method.Any Idea what the problem is now?

Thanks :)

Edit2: It now behaves exactly as expected when I changed `equals` to this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object p) {

    if (this == p)
        return true;
    else if ( !(p instanceof Point) )
        return false;
    else {
        Point that = (Point) p;
        return (that.lat == lat) && (that.lng == lng);
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: There is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839182/can-a-java-array-be-used-as-a-hashmap-key) for the plain Java `Map` case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using *arrays* as the hash keys. That's not going to work - Java doesn't override `hashCode` and `equals` for arrays. (The `Arrays` class provides methods to do this, but it's not going to help you here.) Admittedly I'd expect it to work in this specific case, where you're using the *exact same reference* for both `put` and `containsKey`... When I test your code, it prints `true`. Are you sure you can reproduce it with *exactly* your code?

For example, while I'd expect it to work for the code you've given, I *wouldn't* expect this to work:

```
// Logically equal array, but distinct objects
double[] key = (double[]) startingPoint.clone();
System.out.println(destinations.containsKey(key));
```

It sounds like you shouldn't really be using `double[]` here - you should create a `Point` class which has two `double` variables, and overrides `equals` and `hashCode`.

Additionally, using `double` values in hash keys is *usually* a bad idea anyway, due to the nature of binary floating point arithmetic. That's going to be a problem even using the `Point` idea above... it should be okay if you don't need to actually do any arithmetic (if you're just copying values around) but take great care...

Comment: @Tring: I never suggested that. See my edit for an alternative.

Comment: I implemented what you suggested, and still I have a small issue. can you have a look?

Comment: @Tring: You haven't overridden `equals(Object)` - you've overloaded it with `equals(Point)` which isn't being called...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot hash "equal" arrays and get the same result each time.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(new double[]{1.0, 2.0}.hashCode());
     System.out.println(new double[]{1.0, 2.0}.hashCode());
}
```

will result something like

```
306344348
1211154977
```