# Can an array be used as a HashMap key?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, key

If a `HashMap`'s key is a `String[]` array:

```java
HashMap<String[], String> pathMap;
```

Can you access the map by using a newly created `String[]` array, or does it have to be the same `String[]` object?

```java
pathMap = new HashMap<>(new String[]{"korey", "docs"}, "/home/korey/docs");
String path = pathMap.get(new String[]{"korey", "docs"});
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It will have to be the same object. A `HashMap` compares keys using `equals()` and two arrays in Java are equal only if they are the same object.

If you want value equality, then write your own container class that wraps a `String[]` and provides the appropriate semantics for `equals()` and `hashCode()`. In this case, it would be best to make the container immutable, as changing the hash code for an object plays havoc with the hash-based container classes.

EDIT

As others have pointed out, `List<String>` has the semantics you seem to want for a container object. So you could do something like this:

```
HashMap<List<String>, String> pathMap;

pathMap.put(
    // unmodifiable so key cannot change hash code
    Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("korey", "docs")),
    "/home/korey/docs"
);

// later:
String dir = pathMap.get(Arrays.asList("korey", "docs"));
```

Comment: I think it also uses `hashCode()` to determine the hash of an object.

Comment: @pvorb - Indeed. And two arrays are unlikely to have the same hash code. However, this is not a requirement for any Java implementation. In any case, two references with the same `hashCode()` are then compared using `equals()` to determine if they are the same key.

Comment: @TedHopp I decided to use your suggestion to make a container class. Thanks!

Comment: @KoreyHinton - You're welcome. :) Before doing that, though, check whether `List` does what you need. See my edited answer.

Comment: @TedHopp Cool I just now saw your edit, thanks for showing a working example!

Comment: This all sounded very promising, but when I try to do containsKey I get a `ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`, still researching...

Comment: @MarkBennett - Weird. AFAIK `HashMap.containsKey` does not require keys to implement `Comparable`. It only relies on `hashCode()` and `equals()`. Something else must be going on in your code.

Comment: Note that the collection returned by `Collections.unmodifiableList(List)` is not immutable--if the underlying list is later modified, the hashcode of the unmodifiable list wrapping it will change. So the call to `Collections.unmodifiableList` protects the keys from modification by, for example, a malicious or misguided consumer iterating the keyset and modifying keys, but if the underlying list used as a key could later change, defensive copying is also necessary.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock - Good point. The usual idiom for using `Collections.unmodifiableList(List)` is to not keep a reference to the argument (as in my sample code), so this usually isn't a problem. It's only when the argument is separately modifiable (through a separate reference) that things can get messed up.

Comment: The question would be then: Is there a suitable container class that will wrap an array and provide the needed hasCode() and equals()?  It looks like a very generic thing.

Comment: @FlorianF - You mean for an array of mutable objects? I think an identity hash is the only sensible approach in that case. If the hash code for key objects can change dynamically, a hash-based data structure is unsuitable right from the start.

Answer (score 13):

No, but you can use `List<String>` which will work as you expect!

Comment: This works with a caveat. If you're going to use a `List<String>` as a key in a hash-based collection, the list should be unmodifiable. If the hash code for an object changes while the object is being used as a key in a hash-based collection, the collection generally breaks.

Comment: `List` is an interface, and there no guarantee that an implementation properly overrides equals and hashCode

Comment: @SteveKuo - Yes there is. The documentation for `List` requires any implementation to use a specific semantics for `equals()` and `hashCode()`. The required semantics matches what OP seems to want.

Comment: Indeed, the AbstractList class which is the superclass all list implementations inherit from overrides both hashCode() and equals() methods, so that the element-wise comparison, rather than reference comparison, is reflected.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in Java use `Object`'s `hashCode()` and don't override it (the same thing with `equals()` and `toString()`). So no, you <strike>cannot</strike> shouldn't use arrays as a hashmap key.

Comment: You _can_ use them as a key, it will just use whatever Object does for its hashCode...  Not what he wants, but nothing stopping you from doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a plain Java `Array` as a key in a `HashMap`. (Well you can, but it won't work as expected.)

But you could write a wrapper class that has a reference to the Array and that also overrides `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: No need write a new array wrapper class, one already exists - `ArrayList`

Comment: @SteveKuo Yes, indeed. But maybe you want to write your own, since `ArrayList` is mutable and the array underneath can be replaced internally without you noticing it.

Comment: @pvorb - One can always use `Collections.unmodifiableList(someList)` to turn a `List` into an immutable object.

Comment: @TedHopp: an unmodifiableList is not an immutable one.You still can modify the source list directly.

Comment: @Alex - Yes, you are correct. This was pointed out in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839182/can-a-java-array-be-used-as-a-hashmap-key/16839313#comment65852143_16839191) to my own answer above. See also [my response to that comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839182/can-a-java-array-be-used-as-a-hashmap-key/16839313#comment65854739_16839191).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, where the Strings inside your array are not pathological and do not include commas followed by a space, you can use `Arrays.toString()` as a unique key.  i.e. your `Map` would be a `Map<String, T>`.  And the get/put for an array `myKeys[]` would be

```
T t = myMap.get(Arrays.toString(myKeys));

myMap.put(Arrays.toString(myKeys), myT);
```

Obviously you could put in some wrapper code if desired.

A nice side effect is that your key is now immutable.  Of course, of you change your array myKeys and then try a `get()`, you won't find it.

Hashing of Strings is highly optimized.  So my *guess* is that this solution, though it feels a bit slow and kludgy, will be both faster and more memory efficient (less object allocations) than @Ted Hopp solution using an immutable List.  Just think about whether `Arrays.toString()` is unique for your keys.  If not, or if there is any doubt, (e.g. the String[] comes from user input) use the List.

Answer (score 1):

Like said you need a wrapper class around your array which overrides equality and hashCode.

e.g.

```
/** 
 * We can use this instance as HashKey,
 * the same anagram string will refer the same value in the map.
 */
class Anagram implements CharSequence {

    private final char[] anagram;

    public Anagram(String anagram) {

        this.anagram = anagram.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(this.anagram);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Anagram that = (Anagram) o;
        return Arrays.equals(this.anagram, that.anagram);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Arrays.hashCode(this.anagram);
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {

        return anagram.length;
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index) {

        return anagram[index];
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {

        return new String(anagram).subSequence(start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return Arrays.toString(anagram);
    }
}
```

Otherwise declare your map as [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), then the user knows we need to use the same instance for your CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

Ted Hopp is right it will have to be same object.

For information see this example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String[], String> pathMap;
    pathMap = new HashMap<String[], String>();
    String[] data = new String[]{"korey", "docs"};
    pathMap.put(data, "/home/korey/docs");
    String path = pathMap.get(data);
    System.out.println(path);
}
```

When you run the above code, it will print "docs".

Comment: LOL, thats because you use the same object as key, try to use same array but new created.

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 9*, you can use [`Arrays::compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#compare-T:A-T:A-) method as a comparator for `TreeMap` that compares the *contents* of arrays.

```java
Map<String[], String> map = new TreeMap<>(Arrays::compare);

String[] key1 = {"one", "two"};
String[] key2 = {"one", "two"};
String[] key3 = {"one", "two"};

map.put(key1, "value1");
map.put(key2, "value2");

System.out.println(map.size()); // 1
System.out.println(map.get(key1)); // value2
System.out.println(map.get(key2)); // value2
System.out.println(map.get(key3)); // value2
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to make a `Set` of arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67952865/16119950)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

A running example using the `Arrays` utility and the hash code it provides:

```
String[] key1 = { "korey", "docs" };
String value1 = "/home/korey/docs";
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(Arrays.hashCode(key1), value1);
System.out.println(map);
```

{-1122550406=/home/korey/docs}

This approach is useful if your focus is in storing only. Retrieving using the readable (original) key is simple:

```
String retrievedValue = map.get(Arrays.hashCode(key1));
System.out.println(retrievedValue);
```

/home/korey/docs

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it cannot deal with hash collision when 2 string[] has the same hashCode under Arrays.hashCode().