# A Collection that uses an array for its key/type

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, collections, set

My program has to pass a lot of arrays between threads. I want a collection that can accept an array, and then a contains method will specify whether a Set/Map contains the array (i.e. it is a duplicate or has already been processed by the thread). I assume this collection would have to use `Arrays.equals(a1, a2)`, because the `Object.equals()` method [will not work on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839182/can-a-java-array-be-used-as-a-hashmap-key). Is it possible to write a collection that works like this, or would it fail when autoboxing from, say, int[] to Integer[]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a wrapper for `Array` which overrides `hashCode()` and `equals()` like `Arrays.asList()`.

BTW, you should avoid using arrays and opt for Collections whenever possible. I also recommend you use immutable data structures for multi-threading. Using a mutable object in a Set or as the key of a Map is a terrible idea anyways.

Comment: I would highly recommend storing that hashCode as a variable in that instance if you can. Looping through the elements every time you want the hash can be very costly.

Comment: By wrapper, do you mean an extension of `Array`? Because it's a final class.

Comment: Also, to clarify I do want to use a collection, but something like Set<Integer[]> or Map<Character[], Object>.

Comment: @NobleUplift Wrapper means a wrapper class. I.e. you always wrap the array in this class before you put it into the collection. I.e. instead of using `Set<Integer[]>` you manually build up `Set<List<Integer>>` by converting arrays to `List`s using `Arrays.asList()`.