# HashMap<int[],string> mapping integer array by considering their values

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Given the following code, I get a `null` (what I want is "1234"). But I wish to have a map that could consider the key as equals, if the contents of `int[]` are equals (rather than consider that the references of `int[]`), how should I do it?

```
HashMap<int[], String> maps=new HashMap<int[], String>();
int[] i=new int[]{1,2,3};
int[] j=new int[]{1,2,3};
maps.put(i,"1234");
System.out.print(maps.get(j));
```

I am opened to any map that allows keeping `int[]` as the key (including `TreeMap`) and so on, with the side condition that if that does not hamper on the effectiveness of the map accessing time.

Comment: Wrap the keys with an object that overrides the equals/hashCode properly.

Comment: ... or use TIntArrayList, which wraps an `int[]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a java array be used as a HashMap key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839182/can-a-java-array-be-used-as-a-hashmap-key)

Answer (score 8):

No way to do that with arrays, because they don't override equals() and hashCode(). You should define your own class wrapping the array, which would override `equals()` and `hashCode()` or use a `List<Integer>` as key instead.

Comment: Or pass a custom `Comparator` to the Map's constructor.

Comment: @kocko You can do that for TreeMap, but not HashMap.

Comment: @kocko Is treemap very different from hashmap, if not, i would rather use a map that just need to pass a comparator

Answer (score 3):

Wrap them in a custom object, and use `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` for equality. From the api:

> Returns true if the two specified arrays of ints are equal to one
>   another. Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the
>   same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in
>   the two arrays are equal. In other words, two arrays are equal if they
>   contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array
>   references are considered equal if both are null.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `int[]` uses object identity for `equals()` and `hashCode()`, so it won't work with Map in java. You can use `List<Integer>` instead.

List's [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29) API says

> Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is
>   defined to be the result of the following calculation:
>
> ```
> int hashCode = 1;
>   Iterator<E> i = list.iterator();
>   while (i.hasNext()) {
>       E obj = i.next();
>       hashCode = 31*hashCode + (obj==null ? 0 : obj.hashCode());
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays class use the default equels and hashcode of Object class but it provide another methods called deepHashCode and deepEquls that actually work on the array contains. You can create a class like below that hold your array and the hashcode and equals will be implemented using deepHashCode and deepEquals. Instead of direct array use this class.

```
class MyArray {        
    private Integer[] arrayInstance;

    public void setArray(Integer[] a) {
            this.arrayInstance = a;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + Arrays.deepHashCode(arrayInstance);
            return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                    return true;
            if (obj == null)
                    return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                    return false;
            MyArray other = (MyArray) obj;
            if (!Arrays.deepEquals(arrayInstance, other.arrayInstance))
                    return false;
            return true;
    }
}
```

This is how you can use this class

```
    Integer[] a = {1,2,3,4};
    Integer[] b = {1,2,3,4};

    MyArray m1 = new MyArray();
    m1.setArray(a);

    MyArray m2 = new MyArray();
    m2.setArray(b);

    Map<MyArray, String> m = new HashMap<MyArray, String>();
    m.put(m1, "M1");
    m.put(m2, "M2");

    System.out.println(m.size()); // It would be one
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to define your own class wrapping the array, which would override equals() and hashCode() as shown below:

```
class CustomArrayClass {
    int[] array;
    CustomArrayClass(int n){
        array = new int[n];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj==null || !(obj instanceof CustomArrayClass)){
            return false;
        }
        if(this == obj){
            return true;
        }
        CustomArrayClass sec = (CustomArrayClass) obj;
        return Arrays.equals(this.array, sec.array);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(this.array);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Arrays.toString(this.array);
    }
}
```