# Java put something in a hashmap inside a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

Hey i just wanted to say that iam a java newbie.
so my problem is that the output is: `a - null`
and i dont know why
i did change the HashMap from `HashMap<Integer[], Integer> testHashMap = new HashMap<>();` to `HashMap<Integer, Integer> testHashMap = new HashMap<>();`
and then i worked

```
        HashMap<Integer[], Integer> testHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                Integer[] someInteger = {i, j};
                testHashMap.put(someInteger, (i + j * 4));
            }
        }
        Integer[] someOtherInteger = {0,0};
        System.out.println("a - " + testHashMap.get(someOtherInteger));
```

outPut:"a - null"
outPut should be :"a - 0"

im sorry if this is like a dumb question.

Comment: Use some Point class, with a hashCode() and equals(); missing in int[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Arrays do not provide an override for the equals method and will just do an identity comparision.

Therefor

```
new Integer[]{0,0}.equals(new Integer[]{0,0});
```

will return false and Integer[] simply isn't a usable class to use as a key for a map, because HashMap uses the equals and hashcode methods internally for the keys.

You should consider creating your own custom class for the key that holds those 2 int values and where you override equals and hashcode.

But you can use List and it should work:

```
HashMap<List<Integer>, Integer> testHashMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        List<Integer> someInteger = Arrays.asList(i, j);
        testHashMap.put(someInteger, (i + j * 4));
    }
}
List<Integer> someOtherInteger = Arrays.asList(0,0);
System.out.println("a - " + testHashMap.get(someOtherInteger));
```

will give you your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

As @vakio explained, `hashCode` for arrays does not take into account their contents.

If you really need to use a compound key for a map, replace `Integer[]` key type array with a list `List<Integer>`:

```java
Map<List<Integer>, Integer> testHashMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        List<Integer> someInteger = Arrays.asList(i, j);
        testHashMap.put(someInteger, (i + j * 4));
    }
}
List<Integer> someOtherInteger = Arrays.asList(0, 0);
System.out.println("a - " + testHashMap.get(someOtherInteger)); // a - 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22126808/15487427)

He said as follows

> No way to do that with arrays, because they don't override equals() and hashCode(). You should define your own class wrapping the array, which would override equals() and hashCode() or use a `List<Integer>` as key instead.

What I want to note you is same.

Use `List<Integer>` instead of `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, with the array of Integers, what you essentially store as the key for your map is the object reference of {0,0} or {i,j} in general.

When you’re creating someOtherInteger, Java gives you back another object reference - allocates another memory address. In other words, whenever Java creates a new Object, and array is considered an Object and not a primitive, it allocates a different address for it.

That’s why when calling `get` giving the second value, holding the someOtherInteger array reference, it returns null. This key, reflecting the unique address of someOtherInteger, does not exist in your map.