# extract keys and values from hashmap and insert into more malleable structures

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

As input I have a hashmap which stores as a key an int array of the form `[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,6,0,1]` and as a key a String label, i.e. `science`. What I want to do is extract the array and deposit it into a 2D array. The I want to compare the label to another string and if it is a match save a `1` to `outputs` else save a zero. I thought the code below would do that trick, but it seems not. Where have I gone wrong?

```
   double[][] feature_matrix = new double[ number_of_files ][ globo_dict_size ];
   int[] outputs = new int [ number_of_files ];

   //likely not the best way to do this
   for(int z = 0; z < number_of_files; z++)
   {

       for( Map.Entry< int[] , String > entry : train_freq_count_against_globo_dict.entrySet() ) 
       {
           int[] container_of_feature_vector = entry.getKey();

           for (int q = 0; q < globo_dict_size; q++) 
           {
               feature_matrix[z][q] = container_of_feature_vector[q];
           }
           outputs[z] =  String.valueOf( entry.getValue() ).equals(LABEL) ? 1 : 0;
       }
   }
```

Comment: you are a brave fella using int[] as a key to ur map...

Comment: "as a key an int array" this will not work as you expect, because the `equals` and `hashCode` methods for arrays do not provide value semantics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a java string array be used as a HashMap key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839182/can-a-java-string-array-be-used-as-a-hashmap-key)

Comment: what do you mean? Why won't it work to use an int[] as a key?

Comment: try to run `equals` on two `int[]` and see what you find