# Using String(byte[]) as key to map

Tags: java

I have a program that gets ids from a database returned as a `byte[]`. I want to use those ids (byte arrays) as keys to a map. By default this does not work because what is compared is "object equality" not  "content equality".

The next thing I tried which *seemed* to work is instantiating a String with the `new String(byte[])` constructor. While this *seems* to work I know I'm doing some potentially dodgy things. I am not specifying an encoding which relies on whatever the system default is. I also don't know if all byte sequences will have representation in every encoding.

Is "converting" `byte[]` to `String` for the purpose of doing a `map.put()` and `map.get()` safe? Are there edge cases I'm not considering where this approach would inadvertently create a collision (where 2 different `byte[]`'s with different content could become the same `String`).

Note: The map is stored in memory and only lives for a single application run.
Simple wrapper class I wrote to make my life easier if this approach is viable:

```
public class Cache {

    Map<String, Set<String>> cache = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

    public Cache() {}

    public void put(byte[] key, Set<String> value) {
        cache.put(new String(key), value);
    }

    public Set<String> get(byte[] key) {
        return cache.get(new String(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems related and may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839182/can-a-java-array-be-used-as-a-hashmap-key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably use `Biginteger`. It has a [BigInteger(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte[]%29) constructor and has an effective comparison system.

Comment: This seems pretty straightforward. I'm going to go with this unless there is a blatant reason not to. The only thing I could think being an issue is a byte array with contents with "leading" zeros but this shouldn't be the case for me where that is a reality. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Could you not build a simple wrapper around your `byte[]` array instead?

Something akin to:

```
public class CacheKey {
    private final byte[] key;

    public CacheKey(byte[] key) {
        this.key = key; // You may want to do a defensive copy here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        CacheKey cacheKey = (CacheKey) o;
        return Arrays.equals(key, cacheKey.key);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return key != null ? Arrays.hashCode(key) : 0;
    }
}
```

And use that as the map key? It would be a little more lightweight than using the built in String object and makes the key type actually clear.

Comment: Hey this might work too. Does Arrays.hashCode(prim[]) produce a hash based on content of the array?

Comment: That hashcode and equals method were actually generated by my IDE.
[Arrays.hashcode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28byte[]%29) guarantees a call to [Arrays.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte[],%20byte[]%29) between two arrays with the same hashcode will evaluate to true, so it must do.