# Adding entries to HashMap become null after method ends

Tags: java, null, hashmap

I have this class:

```
    public class MyClass{

        private static Map<int[], Terrain> allTerrain = new HashMap<int[], Terrain>();

        public static void main(String[] args){
            populate();
            int[] test = {0, 0};
            System.out.println(allTerrain.get(test));
        }

        private static void populate() {
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                int[] index = {i, i};
                allTerrain.put(index, new Terrain());
            }
            int[] test = {0, 0};
            System.out.println(allTerrain.get(test));
        }

    }
```

Inside the method the `allTerrain.get()` method returns the instance of the object, but when I use `allTerrain.get()` outside of the method, it returns `null` for all the entries.
Everything runs on the main thread so concurrency is not a problem (I think).
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array as a key to your map as you are doing won't work unfortunately.
[Can a java array be used as a HashMap key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839182/can-a-java-array-be-used-as-a-hashmap-key)

Perhaps try an Integer
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not retrieving the value from the `allTerrain` map both inside the scope and outside.

```
null
null
```

The problem, is that when you use an object for keys in a `HashMap`, it needs to implement `hashcode` and `equals` in a useful way. Arrays with the same values are not considered equal. Therefor they don't reference the same key

```
Boolean equal = new int[]{1, 2}.equals(new int[]{1, 2}) // is false
```

Comment: Well I don't know why, but when run inside the method it is returning things like: `com.terrain.Terrain@4f47d241`

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays are equal only if they are the same object. One `int[]{0,0}` is not the same as another `int[]{0,0}`. You could define a **type class** for storing composite key or I'd say use `lombok` `@value` annotation, it creates sensible equals and hashCode method.